# Are there ways to delete custom record types from CloudKit Dashboard?

Tags: cloudkit

Some of the fields have been changed and I need to delete record types in the Dashboard and start over. 
[Screenshot of my dashboad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTrm6.png)

I need to delete all three record types: coordinates, cravingLog, and journalLog. I tried clicking on "Delete Record Type" button at the bottom, but I can't click it. It won't let me delete them.

I looked everywhere on the Dashboard for help, but I could not find any ways to delete them.

Comment: Is resetting the dev environment an option?

Answer (score 2):

You can only delete record types in the development schema, and only as long as the schema has not been deployed to production.
As soon as it has been deployed, deletion is no longer possible - even if the delete button is enabled. Pushing the button then gives an error message.
The only way to get rid of such record types is to use a new container. But containers that are no longer needed cannot be deleted either...